# Splitting date in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

How do I split string in mongodb?
I have date as "2013-10-01T10:53:57.171Z" and I want to split it into just date "2013-10-01".
I am using mongodb with ireport.

Comment: Use [**Moment.js**](http://momentjs.com/) its a javascript date library for parsing, validating, manipulating, and formatting dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$substr (aggregation operator)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/substr/) to split string. You can use the following code to get date from the given string.

```
> db.myObject.aggregate({$group: {_id : {$substr : ["$date", 0,10]}}});
```

And it will return the result as follows :

```
"result" : [ { "_id" : "2013-10-01" } ]
```